# MathTime Professional 2 fonts on only a single line?

Tags: math-mode, mtpro

How could one use MathTime Professional 2 fonts on **only one line of text** (in math mode) in a document, where every *other* line of text (in math mode) displays as though the mtpro2 package is not being used at all?

Comment: What would you be using instead of MathTime?

Comment: Hi @Mico I am using amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts

Comment: `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `amsfonts` don't load any non-default font families. Are you using `Computer Modern` for your document? And, are you saying you would like to use `Computer Modern` (both as a text and as a math font) everywhere in the paper *except* for the material of one line, which should use `Times` text and `MathTime Professional` math fonts? I assume you're aware that `Times` and `Computer Modern` don't harmonize particularly well, right?

Comment: @Mico I appreciate your reply. I'm using Times for the document. I'm trying to use mtpro in math mode on only one line, and have the other lines in math mode to act as if mtpro2 was never used. I don't mind if they don't harmonize.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I meant mtpro2, not mtpro.

Comment: Would this one-off special line happen to be a displayed equation?

Comment: @Mico It should be on its own line centered, so if it makes it easier it could be a displayed in equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat kludgy suggestion:

Create a one-line document using the `standalone` document class. Suppose this text file is called `mmm.tex`:

```
%% mmm.tex 
\documentclass[border=0.25pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle a^2+b^2=c^2$
\end{document}
```

Compile this tex file; let's assume the resulting pdf file is called `mmm.pdf`.

Next, set up a "regular" tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[ \raisebox{-0.25ex}{\includegraphics{mmm}} \]
\end{document}
```

The contents of `mmm.pdf` -- the one-line equation -- will show up as the contents of the display-math environment. Use the first argument of `\raiesebox` to raise (positive argument) or lower (negative argument) the graphic.

Comment: Thanks Mico, I will try your suggestion and see how it works!